# Парсинг текста с сайта на Python

Tags: python, парсер

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Всем добрый день. Как проходят майские праздники? Возник вопрос по поводу парсинга сайта на Python. Есть сайт: https://www.rttnews.com/CorpInfo/ConferenceCalls.aspx?Date=04-May-2020 Нужно спарсить текст блоков, на фотографии постарался изобразить максимально понятно. Моя программа парсит только первый текст и выводит его, но мне нужны тексты не только из первого блока (верхней строки), но и следующие 7 штук. Подскажите, что нужно исправить в программе, чтобы парсился не только первый, а все 8 текстов с веб страницы?
Вот код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    r.encoding = 'utf8'
    return r.text


def get_link(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    text = soup.find('div', {'class': 'ecoCalContent'}).find('div', {'class': 'tblContent5'}).text
    print(text)


get_link(get_html('https://www.rttnews.com/CorpInfo/ConferenceCalls.aspx?Date=04-May-2020'))

# выводится первый текст, а нужны все 8 с веб страницы: 
# https://www.rttnews.com/CorpInfo/ConferenceCalls.aspx?Date=04-May-2020
```

Заранее большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете искать одновременно по нескольким классам. Для этого передайте их списком:

```py
{'class': ['ecoCalContent', 'ecoCalAltContent']}
```

***Пример:***

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


URL = 'https://www.rttnews.com/CorpInfo/ConferenceCalls.aspx'
html = requests.get(URL, params={'Date': '04-May-2020'}).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

divs = soup.findAll('div', {'class': ['ecoCalContent', 'ecoCalAltContent']})

result = []
for div in divs:
    text = div.find('div', {'class': 'tblContent5'}).text
    result.append(text)
print(*result)
```

***stdout:***

```html
Cirrus Logic Inc. (CRUS) will host a conference call at 5:00 PM ET on May 4, 2020, to discuss Q4 20 earnings results.



To access the live webcast, log on to www.cirrus.com



For a replay call, dial (416) 621-4642 or (800) 585-8367 (Access Code: 9199070).



 Varian Medical Systems (VAR) will host a conference call at 4:30 PM ET on May 4, 2020, to discuss Q2 20 earnings results.



To access the live webcast, log on to www.varian.com/investor  American States Water Co. (AWR) will host a conference call at 2:00 PM ET on May 4, 2020, to discuss Q4 19 earnings results.



To access the live webcast, log on to http://americanstateswatercompany.gcs-web.com/news-events/event-calendar



 WEC Energy Group. (WEC) will host a conference call at 2:00 PM ET on May 4, 2020, to discuss Q1 20 earnings results.



To access the live webcast, log on to wecenergygroup.com



To listen to the call, dial 877-683-2228 (US) or 647-689-5446 (International), Conference ID: 7898148.



For a replay call, dial 800-585-8367 (US) or 416-621-4642 (International), Conference ID: 7898148.



 Sempra Energy (SRE) will host a conference call at 12:00 PM ET on May 4, 2020, to discuss Q1 20 earnings results.



To access the live webcast, log on to sempra.com



For a replay call, dial (888) 203-1112 with passcode 8909332. NAPCO Security Technologies Inc. (NSSC) will host a conference call at 11:00 AM ET on May 4, 2020, to discuss Q3 20 earnings results.



To access the live webcast, log on to www.napcosecurity.com 



To listen to the call, dial 1-877-407-4018 (US) or 1-201-689-8471 (International).



For a replay call, dial 1-844-512-2921 (US) or 1-412-317-6671 (International) with access code 13702840.  Loews Corp. (L) will host a conference call at 11:00 AM ET on May 4, 2020, to discuss Q4 19 earnings results.



To access the live webcast, log on to www.loews.com



To listen to the call, dial (877) 692-2592 (US) or (973) 582-2757 (International) with conference ID number 6097643.



For a replay call, dial (800) 585-8367 (US) or (404) 537-3406 (International) with conference ID number 6097643 .



  Wabtec Corporation (WAB) will host a conference call at 10:00 AM ET on May 4, 2020, to discuss Q1 20 earnings results.



To access the live webcast, log on to www.WabtecCorp.com



For a replay call, dial 1-877-344-7529 or 1-412-317-0088 (Access code: 10142434).
```

Comment: @Илья Что значит _"не корректно"_? У Вас возникает какая-то ошибка?

Comment: Программа ничего не выводит

Comment: soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
text = soup.findAll('div', {'class': ['ecoCalContent', 'ecoCalAltContent']}).find('div', {'class': 'tblContent5'}).text
print(text)

Comment: что если так попробовать?

Comment: @Илья Я знаю... ведь я не добавил ни один `print`. Добавьте в конце `print(*result)`, если Вам это необходимо.

Comment: Извините, вообще не заметил ... Спасибо!

Comment: @Илья Почему? Вроде, то. Добавил `stdout` на всякий случай. Много переводов строк, конечно. Но они были изначально в `HTML`.

Comment: Программа работает, большое спасибо